# Is there a neat method to output text to debugging pane?

Tags: c++, debugging, macros, console

I would like to display some log messages when debugging. One option is to use the very ugly

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "I'm in debug mode!\n";
#endif
```

In the [JUCE](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) library, there is a nice macro that outputs text to the debugging pane

```
DBG("I'm in debug mode!")
```

The juce solution also allows you to do neat stuff like the following that would be desirable

```
int x = 4;
DBG(String("x=") + String(x))
```

I would like to know if a similarly neat method exists in std:: or boost::

Comment: The thingy at the bottom of the xcode window :)

Comment: Well, not everyone uses xcode, and your question makes no mention of it. ;)

Comment: Ideally it would be the thigy at the bottom of xcode or Visual studio ;)

Comment: See, now we're getting somewhere. But what if I'm coding in Emacs, which doesn't *have* a debug pane? My point is there is not always a debug pane. And even when there is, the way in which you write to it differs (xcode just prints the standard output stream to the debug pane I believe, but Visual Studio requires you to use the `DebugOutputString()` function. So making a single universal solution is pretty much impossible. :)

Comment: The one in JUCE works nicely on both platforms

Comment: In VS you can use `OutputDebugPrint`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @jalf, @Mike: did you both mean `OutputDebugString`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just write your own:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DBG(x) std::cout << x;
#else
#define DBG(x)
#endif
```

For namespaces

```
namespace DBG
{
inline void DBG(const char* x)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << x;
#endif
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to put that into a namespace?

Comment: @learnvst: macro's don't fit in namespaces, but the macro version allows this: `DBG("first: " << first << ", second: " << second);`

Comment: @stefaanv I know the behavior is not the same, but there's really no other way to have it in a namespace.

Comment: I now have the solution I want. I use the second example above, but taking `std::string` as the function input. I can then use `boost::lexical_cast` when using `int x = 4; utils::DBG("abc" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>x)` to add numeric values if needed. I'll roll with that unless someone suggests an even neater way to do this.

Comment: @Luchian: I agree.  I just showed the OP, that he still has to make a choice between both, which apparently, he did. (although, I would not want to see lexical_cast all over my logs)

Comment: @stefaanv, just noticed your earlier comment. Now I'm on the fence again (lexical_cast all over the show will make things ugly again). I'll ponder this and make a decision. Thanks for all your combined help!

Comment: Ok, change of plans. I will use the macro version, put it in my utils header file and call it DBGM so it doesn't clash with the juce DBG macro if i decide to include this lib in a juce project later. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want something like printf, you should use a bit another macros:

```
void DebugPrintLn(const char* format, ...);
inline void Nothing(...) {}

#ifdef DEBUG
#define DBG DebugPrintLn
#else
#define DBG Nothing // Or __noop on Visual C++
#endif
```

Using `Nothing` is portable, but arguments still computed (__noop guarantees that any of argument will be *not* computed, VC++ specific). Better if you can use macros variable arguments (both available on GCC and latest VC++): you may even skip any argument computation in portable way:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DBG(...) DebugPrintLn(__VAR_ARGS__)
#else
#define DBG(...) ((void)0)
#endif
```

In any case, you use it the same way:

```
DBG("Lucky day: %s %i", "Friday", 13);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also written my own portable TRACE macro. I share it here:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_TRACE
#  ifdef _MSC_VER
#    include <windows.h>
#    include <sstream>
#    define TRACE(x)                           \
     do {  std::stringstream s;  s << (x);     \
           OutputDebugString(s.str().c_str()); \
        } while(0)
#  else
#    include <iostream>
#    define TRACE(x)  std::clog << (x)
#  endif        // or std::cerr << (x) << std::flush
#else
#  define TRACE(x)
#endif
```

example:

```
#define ENABLE_TRACE  //can depend on _DEBUG or NDEBUG macros
#include "my_above_trace_header.h"

int main (void)
{
   int     v1 = 123;
   double  v2 = 456.789;
   TRACE ("main() v1="<< v1 <<" v2="<< v2 <<'\n');
}
```

Any improvements/suggestions/contributions are welcome ;-)