# how to write to output window in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am able to compile and run my visual c++ program.  It is not a console application. I am modifying an existing MFC application. I am trying to troubleshoot my program. I cannot run in debug and get the traces I need because my program also reads the mouse cursor. I also tried to use a messagebox to output this string, but again, a message box interferes with the mouse.

In the output window, I right-click and make sure that Program Output is enabled.

```
cout << "something" << endl;
```

However, in the output window, I do not see anything.

Looking at SO posts, I tried

```
std::string stro = "something ";
OutputDebugString(stro);
```

> error C2664: 'void OutputDebugStringW(LPCWSTR)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'LPCWSTR'

So changed to std::wstring stro

and

```
OutputDebugString(stro.c_str());
```

to append an int, I had to

```
std::wostringstream wso;    
wso << i;   
stro = stro + wso.str();
OutputDebugString(stro.c_str());
```

But I cannot see output in the window when not running in DEBUG. Is there any way to see output in non-DEBUG? This is surprisingly frustrating.

In the comments, writing a separate overloaded class was suggested; this seems like overkill. Java has System.out.println even in GUI programs. Android has Log.v(). Such a pity the equivalent is not available here.

Comment: Looks like you need to proof-read your post and edit as needed so that it is clear to everyone else what is it that you are asking

Comment: @YePhlcK sorry it wasn't clearly worded

Comment: @KateGregory It is not a console application. I am modifying an existing MFC application. But there is no other choice in the drop down  menu in the Output window apart from Build, Debug.

Comment: @KateGregory I am trying to troubleshoot my program. I cannot run in debug and get the traces I need because my program also reads the mouse cursor. I also tried to use a messagebox to output this string, but again, a message box interferes with the mouse.

Comment: @KateGregory Still troubleshooting... but that was very helpful! if you can post your comment as a answer, I shall accept it!

Comment: It is not impossible, but are you *really* planning to ship Visual Studio along with your app to your customer?  You can use SysInternals' DebugView utility as an alternative.

Comment: @HansPassant in deleted comments I established that this output is for the developer who is trying to understand the app, not for users of the app in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console applications have console output, which is what `cout` sends to. Since this isn't a console application, you'll want to try another approach. It's strange you object "I don't see Debug output when I'm not in Debug", that's the point of it - don't use `OutputDebugString` and expect it to be for something other than debug output.

I think the best way to understand what your application is doing, without interacting with it under the debugger (I know the frustration of trying to debug event handlers that keep being re-triggered by your debugging activities) is to try tracepoints. I [blogged about them](http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/Tracepoints.aspx) back in 2006 and they're still a great technique. Reading the mouse cursor won't interfere with tracepoints, and you can turn them on and off without rebuilding your app or making any code changes.

Set up a breakpoint, then right-click the red dot and choose When Hit. You can adjust the default message that goes into the output window to show you any values you are interested in - you can even call functions in the trace message, as you can see in the blog entry where I call the size() method of a collection. If necessary, you can even debug a release build.

Comment: Other (similar) options include writing to a log file and `tail`'ing it in a different window; or opening a separate window to output your debug info into(unless you are running in full-screen, of course - but even then you can use multiple monitors); or dedicating a portion of your application's window (screen) to debug info

Comment: @Kate Gregory strangely, I am seeing the messages in tracepoints are not in order. Perhaps because string 'stro' is in a background thread? I am wondering if tracepoints will not work here.

Comment: more likely, the tracepoints are telling you that things are not happening in the order you think they are

Comment: @KateGregory Perhaps not. The order that the output window shows the messages is different from what is on the screen graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Actually OutputDebugStrng *should* work in release builds - as long as you're running the app from the debugger.  However cout cannot route output to the VS output pane.

If you already have a lot of 'cout' style debugging code, the easiest route might be to replace it with a custom ostream overload which does print to the output pane. [Here's one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1053/Using-an-output-stream-for-debugging),  [here's another](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27952/Debug-logging-with-STL-stream-operators).

If you can rewrite the debugging code completely, some [macro wrappers around OutputDebugString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447899/is-there-a-neat-method-to-output-text-to-debugging-pane) might be better for you.

Comment: I looked at it; writing a separate overloaded class is a lot. Java has System.out.println even in GUI programs. Android has Log.v(). Such a pity the equivalent is not available here

Comment: Yes it is, and it is called OutputDebugString.  The code in the links wraps it in an ostream interface.

Answer (score 1):

Having a stdout/stderr console window for debugging is very useful, and I always miss it when working on WinMain based apps.  I use this code fragment to create a console for windows apps (and chain it in with existing loggers, etc.)  After running this, your cout/cerr should work fine.  OutputDebugString output can be seen outside of DevStudio using the DebugView app, but I prefer this:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
...

//  DOS box console for stdin/stdout/stderr
void makeConsole()
{
    AllocConsole();

    HANDLE handle_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long)handle_out, _O_TEXT);
    FILE* hf_out = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
    setvbuf(hf_out, NULL, _IONBF, 2);
    *stdout = *hf_out;

    HANDLE handle_in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long)handle_in, _O_TEXT);
    FILE* hf_in = _fdopen(hCrt, "r");
    setvbuf(hf_in, NULL, _IONBF, 2);
    *stdin = *hf_in;

    HANDLE handle_err = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long)handle_err, _O_TEXT);
    FILE* hf_err = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
    setvbuf(hf_err, NULL, _IONBF, 2);
    *stderr = *hf_err;

    ios::sync_with_stdio();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the results seem similar to tracepoints - see comments above - the messages seem out of order. Also, when I click esc to stop execution, the console disappears - I have to run in debug mode so I can pause execution and keep the console.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but these issues don't sound related to having a console or not.  Messages appearing out of order are likely due to multiple threads (if the content is interleaved, you may want to use a mutex to keep it readable).  The console will not pause execution (unless you have a readline() or read to stdin in your code, of course).  I don't understand what you're describing re. hitting escape and the console disappearing.  I leave the console up for the duration of the debugging session.